# Could not find dart in flutter sdk in your flutter project?

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am using mac and i have installed vs code ide for developement, now i am not able to create new project and no suggetions are given in the ide and also it does not found any error and also i have installed both the plugins i.e  flutter and dart but still it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run flutter doctor and post the screenshot here.
Run it in terminal "flutter doctor"

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded flutter sdk from https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos  Despite plugins you also need this.